# Geonetwork web interface stays blank

Tags: geonetwork

I am installing Geonetwork 4.0.6, but when set the data directory `/var/lib/geonetwork_data` the web interfaz not show content. I am check the log file `/var/lib/tomcat9/catalina.out` and get this error `ERROR org.apache.jcs.auxiliary.disk.indexed.IndexedDiskCache - Region [xlink] Failure initializing for fileName: xlink and root directory: jcs_caching [2022-03-18 09:38:20] [info] java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/tomcat9/jcs_caching/xlink.data (No existe el fichero o el directorio)`.
I have searched for information about this error but there is nothing about it; If anyone knows what it is due to?

Comment: do the locations specified exist , and does the tomcat user have access to them

Comment: The location does not exist but I cannot find information on how to add said directory